# How can I combine child nodes across two or more XML files using XSL?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am trying to combine XML files using XSL. I've looked on stackoverflow, google, and elsewhere for clues. I've found similar questions or topics, but nothing that exactly matches what I'm trying to do.

I've tried leveraging what I can glean from these sources but I can't seem to quite get the result I'm looking for. So...to **S/O** for a quick consult!

Here is my current approach:

Input file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<protocol>
  <message_exchanges>
    <message_exchange id="1"/>
    <message_exchange id="2"/>
  </message_exchanges>
  <message_types>
    <message_type id="1"/>
    <message_type id="2"/>
    <message_type id="3"/>
  </message_types>
</protocol>
```

Input file2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<protocol>
  <message_exchanges>
    <message_exchange id="3"/>
    <message_exchange id="4"/>
  </message_exchanges>
  <message_types>
    <message_type id="4"/>
    <message_type id="5"/>
    <message_type id="6"/>
  </message_types>
</protocol>
```

Input index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<index>
  <component>file1.xml</component>
  <component>file2.xml</component>
</index>
```

combine.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="index">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="component">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

.....help me fix / finish this file

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

desired_result.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<protocol>
  <message_exchanges>
    <message_exchange id="1"/>
    <message_exchange id="2"/>
    <message_exchange id="3"/>
    <message_exchange id="4"/>
  </message_exchanges>
  <message_types>
    <message_type id="1"/>
    <message_type id="2"/>
    <message_type id="3"/>
    <message_type id="4"/>
    <message_type id="5"/>
    <message_type id="6"/>
  </message_types>
</protocol>
```

1,000 bonus points if you can help me add an attribute on the fly:

```
<message_type id="1" src="file1.xml"/>
<message_type id="4" src="file2.xml"/>
```

I am loading and applying the XSL file to the XML index file using PHP's XSLTProcessor, so I could load the source file names into the processor as a parameter if that would be useful / easier to achieve adding the `src` attribute.

Thanks! Let me know if I can clarify anything further.

[The most useful link I've found so far and the basis of my current approach](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/)

Comment: Oops, no, not intentional. Fixed now.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a fairly short, generic and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where template parameters becomes useful. This is the shortest and simplest transform I'm actually able to produce. **It handles two or more files.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="index">
        <protocol>
            <message_exchanges>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="component">
                    <xsl:with-param name="message" select="'message_exchanges'"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </message_exchanges>
            <message_types>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="component">
                    <xsl:with-param name="message" select="'message_types'"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </message_types>
        </protocol>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="component">
        <xsl:param name="message"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(.)/*/*[name()=$message]/*">
            <xsl:with-param name="comp" select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message_type|message_exchange">
        <xsl:param name="comp" select="''"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="$comp"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with output:

```
<protocol>
   <message_exchanges>
      <message_exchange id="1" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_exchange id="2" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_exchange id="3" src="file2.xml"/>
      <message_exchange id="4" src="file2.xml"/>
   </message_exchanges>
   <message_types>
      <message_type id="1" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_type id="2" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_type id="3" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_type id="4" src="file2.xml"/>
      <message_type id="5" src="file2.xml"/>
      <message_type id="6" src="file2.xml"/>
   </message_types>
</protocol>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for designing it to handle a variable number of input files (which is indeed what I wanted).

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFilename1" select="/*/component[1]"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vFilename2" select="/*/component[2]"/>

 <xsl:template match="index">
  <protocol>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($vFilename1)"/>
  </protocol>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="message_exchanges|message_types">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "document($vFilename2)/*/*[name()=name(current())]/*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pFilename" select="$vFilename2"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="message_exchanges/* | message_types/*">
  <xsl:param name="pFilename" select="$vFilename1"/>

  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pFilename"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<index>
  <component>file1.xml</component>
  <component>file2.xml</component>
</index>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<protocol>
   <message_exchanges>
      <message_exchange id="1" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_exchange id="2" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_exchange id="3" src="file2.xml"/>
      <message_exchange id="4" src="file2.xml"/>
   </message_exchanges>
   <message_types>
      <message_type id="1" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_type id="2" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_type id="3" src="file1.xml"/>
      <message_type id="4" src="file2.xml"/>
      <message_type id="5" src="file2.xml"/>
      <message_type id="6" src="file2.xml"/>
   </message_types>
</protocol>
```

Comment: The question is actually asking "How can I combine child nodes across two or more XML files using XSL?"

Comment: @empo, And how does your comment relate to my answer?

Comment: It seems you have shown how to combine child nodes across **two** specific XML files. The presented transform is not very useful if you have say, 100 files to merge. See my answer for a more general solution.

Comment: @empo, Yes, and this is what the OP wants. There are many possible generalizations and it isn't time well spent to hypothesize.

Comment: The title asks for "two or more" files.

Comment: Sure, but the question itself puts emphasis on two files. As we well know very often in SO titles are inaccurate and misleading.